# Nginx: WS upgrade breaks for Android OS < 5

Tags: android, nginx, websocket

I am using nginx for **wss** to **ws** forwarding. The **ws** server is running on chrome-android (the debugging port). The **ws** server runs perfectly fine when tested independently. However I want a wss request.
 I am successfully able to run the same for android mobiles having OS >= 5.0.
However it doesn't work with Android mobile having OS < 5.0.

When I tcp-dump on the ws port, same request is being sent from nginx in both cases: Android >=5 and Android < 5. But Android phone with version < 5 gives "404 response".

I think that nginx http -> ws upgrade might not be working properly.

My nginx.conf file is http://pastebin.com/NcYg0XBv .

Kindly mention if I am going wrong somewhere.